# Install Composer without curl (local)

Tags: php, ubuntu, laravel, composer-php, phar

I have to run a Laravel Project on a customers Server, Mcrypt is already installed but I can't  run "composer install" because composer is missing. Problem here is, that I can't run

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

because I don't get a connection to other server "outside".

So does anybody know, if I can save the file local and upload it with FTP and run it?
Already tried to save the /installer as a file and run it with "asdf | php" but it didn't work. I also downloaded the composer.phar file but how do I run the .phar file?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Downloading the composer phar file as you have done is a sufficient alternative.

Usage:

`php composer.phar command`

Docs: https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md

---

<del>However, I am fairly sure composer depends on curl, at least as far as updating/installing packages goes. So if you're intending to use those features you'll need curl anyway.*</del>

<del>*citation needed.</del>

*edit*:

I am currently looking through the composer source and I can't yet find a reference to curl. It appears to use stream_context_create, and the manual page for that method doesn't mention curl either. So maybe it'll work without curl...